Discord.py button won't register click
I'am trying to code a bot in python using discord.py. But I can't get it to continue to next section of the code after clicking one of the buttons. The code looks like this:
await interaction.response.send_message(embed = embed, view=vyber_kolej())

    await bot.wait_for('button', check=lambda button: button.author == interaction.user)
    embed.remove_field(0)
    embed.add_field(name="Rocnik", value="vyber ročník žáka", inline=False)
    await interaction.followup.send(embed = embed, view = vyber_rocniku())

And the button code like this:
@discord.ui.button(label="Modrá ", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey)
    async def modra(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        self.kolej = "Modrá"

I have tried events like "button", "button_click" or even "interaction" but none of them worked and it just didn't send anything. I read through the whole documentation of discord.py and ask multiple AI's but none of them knew what to do.

better show minimal working code which we could easily copy and run.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

discord may catch all errors and hides them. You may need to change settings in logging to see error messages in console - Setting Up Logging

@furas print debugging worked. Ty for help!!
